# ngx-text-diff npm module is not working in angular 14

Tags: javascript, angular, angular14

when installing the module getting the below error.

code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "^>=6.0.0" of package "@angular/cdk@^>=6.0.0": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.

package.json file have dependency installed for this module.

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^14.0.1",
"@angular/animations": "^14.2.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^14.2.6",
"@angular/common": "^14.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^14.2.0",
"@angular/core": "^14.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "^14.2.0",
"@angular/material": "^14.2.6",
"@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^14.2.6",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.0",
"@angular/router": "^14.2.0",
"@ctrl/ngx-codemirror": "^5.1.1",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^13.1.0",
"@ngxs/devtools-plugin": "^3.7.5",
"@ngxs/logger-plugin": "^3.7.5",
"@ngxs/store": "^3.7.5",
"@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
"apexcharts": "^3.19.3",
"bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
"codemirror": "^5.65.6",
"compression-webpack-plugin": "^10.0.0",
"core-js": "^3.26.0",
"crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
"diff-match-patch": "^1.0.5",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"jquery": "^3.6.1",
"ng-apexcharts": "^1.5.0",
"ng-diff-match-patch": "^3.0.1",
"ngx-echarts": "^15.0.1",
"ngx-toastr": "^15.2.1",
"popper.js": "^1.16.1",
"rxjs": "~7.5.0",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
"tslib": "^2.3.0",
"zone.js": "~0.11.4"
},
```

Is there any plugin which can check the difference line by line ?

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [official issue](https://github.com/ABenassi87/ngx-text-diff/issues/62)

> A workaround is to run:
>
> npm i ngx-text-diff --legacy-peer-deps Which will make npm ignore the
> syntax errors in semantic versions.

or

> Just use Yarn

Comment: this command is removing other packages.

Comment: If anything it may remove/re-version peer dependencies, which is expected. Just follow the official issue and comment in there.